# Stream WebRTC from an RTSP stream

Tags: webrtc, vlc, rtsp

Currently I have an RTSP stream coming from my IP camera, I have of course the IP and if I try to display it on vlc it all work good (rtsp://IP:PORT/channel).
The next step is to show it on my web - be able to integrate it as a js video component, is there any way to convert it to WebRTC/HTTP?
Maybe using vlc (because i'm using device with no GUI)?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify "show it on my web" ?

Comment: Be able to integrate it as a js video component.
I'm sorry this is the description but I'm only in charge of the camera streaming but not on the web.

Comment: Kurento / Ant Media Server / Unreal Media Server

Answer (score 1):

You will need some sort of 'Protocol Bridge'. The lucky thing is that RTSP is really just a subset of WebRTC (they both use RTP). What you do need is for something to handle ICE, DTLS and SRTP for you.

A project I use is [RTSPToWebRTC](https://github.com/deepch/RTSPtoWebRTC) to do this. There are lots of other options out there though!