# How can one play RTSP videos on browser with lowest possible latency?

Tags: web, webrtc, video-streaming, rtsp

I would like to know how surveillance camera companies stream cameras on their websites with low latency. So far I've found out that most cameras stream with RTSP protocol and it needs to be converted to enable browser streaming.
It seems like that webRTC is the best option but there aren't many resources on how to convert RTSP to webRTC.
There is also the option to send raw images to web page via websocket but I couldn't find a way to implement that either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stream WebRTC from an RTSP stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62874744/stream-webrtc-from-an-rtsp-stream)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for low latency streaming WebRTC is the best choice in most cases.

You will need a server to convert RTSP->WebRTC. There are many opensource solutions, see [RTSP to WEBRTC live video streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61672575/rtsp-to-webrtc-live-video-streaming)

Comment: I did try to use the tools mentioned in the answers to that question but none of them was successful. Do you know any tutorials I could use?

Comment: I do use janus gateway with streaming plugin for rtsp->browser. But setting it up might be a bit tedious. Installing instructions and api documentation can be found on the project's page. They provide you with sdk, but you will need to write client-side code to display the videos.

Comment: https://github.com/deepch/RTSPtoWebRTC is great as on this answer already posted, there are a lot of difference implementations on ip cameras vendors. Older models just use mjpeg or jpeg images over websocket or push/stream protocols. Newer cameras use sometimes use MSE (fragmented mp4), or webrtc also there are implementations of rtsp over websocket like AXIS did. I have very good results with RTSPtoWebRTC because there is no transcoding if your camera provide h264 and and no resources are needed for that. Also you gain the benefit of gpu decoding on the web browser =)